# WPF Create setup project including database

Tags: c#, database, wpf, installation, deployment

How can I include a database to the installer, so the program could work with the database from any PC? Also, what should I write in the connectionString then, because now I'm working with this connection string, but when I install the application to another PC the programme doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have problems that can be solved by using a slightly different method.
First of all the database you want to use is in the app right ? If it is, consider using SQLite for exemple which is integrated to your app so the connection string is relative to your app so the problem of the connection string disappear.
Then for the filling of the database there is (on my knowledge) no method to do but you can write code that wiil fulfill the database for you by the launch, the method can be simplified but it is for you to understand.

1. The database is created with the app
2. You have a method that check if the database is empty (or just a main table, you can also make a line for the specific use of the method to check if the database is empty)
3. If the database is empty you fill it with the datas you have to put into
4. That's all

I'm far to be as advanced as many of people here, but this method could do the trick until you find a better way.

Here is a link for SQLite on .NET : https://anceret-matthieu.developpez.com/tutoriels/utiliser-sqlite-a-traversnet/

Have a nice day and welcome to StackOverflow.